# dynamically build both <th>'s and <tr>'s

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

The amount of columns in a table is based upon the amount of data in a table. The amount of rows in a table is based on the amount of rows in a different table. An example of these tables are below

```
environments        patches
  id | name           id |    name
 ____|______         ____|____________
   1 | dev             1 | firstPatch
   2 | test            2 | secondPatch
   3 | prod            3 | thirdPatch
```

The end result of what I'm looking for would be the following `<table>`

```
 _________________________________
| Patch Name  | dev | test | prod |
|_____________|_____|______|______|
| thirdPatch  |     |      |      |
| secondPatch |  x  |      |      |
|_firstPatch__|_____|______|______|
```

I understand how I could use a `while()` loop to build the table headers. And I understand how I could use a `while()` to build the rows.

```
echo "<tr>";
while ($env = $listEnvs->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<th>".$env['name']."</th>"
}
echo "</tr>";

--AND--

while ($patch = $listPatches->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<tr><td>".$patch['name']."</td></tr>";
}
```

What I am struggling with is that the cells for each patch/environment pair are going to have data that is pulled from several other tables. So knowing the `patch.id` as well as the `environment.id` is important. Example the cell with the `x` is `patch.id = 2, environment.id = 1` When constructing the table, how can I make sure each cell has this necessary information?

Comment: can you specify table looks? P.S. May be you need to use join to combine SQL rows to one table which can be the data for the html table?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. My mysql knowledge is fairly limited. The basic `CRUD` stuff

Comment: Check SQL JOIN http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp maybe it will help you.

Comment: And to build Cartesian product table you can pick first table values (columns) and for each of them build rows from other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create an array like `$content[$patch.id][$environment.id]`.

Then you can add `echo($content[$patch.id][$environment.id])` to your `while` of the `$patch`. You walk through the patches, so `$patch.id` is known. For `$environment.id`, you should make an array with all environment.id's and walk through it with `$environment.id[i]`, where `$i` should be increased with each new column (and set to 0 when a new row is started).

In (bad) pseudo-code:

```
walkthrough environments {

    save array with environments
    echo table headers

}

walk through patches {

    echo table 'row headers'

    walk through environment array {

        echo content[patch.id][environment.id]

    }

}
```

Comment: I hope you get what I mean, it's a little bit hard to describe ;-)